# Configure the final apk name in Qt Creator

Tags: android, qt

By default QtCreator when generates the apk for Android uses QtApp-debug.apk as the final name.

Anyone knows if that name can be configured?

I've been searching if there's a place where you can change that "QtApp" part but couldn't find it. I've even found a reply from Bogdan suggesting to rename that final file [https://www.mail-archive.com/qt-creator@qt-project.org/msg02821.html]

Before giving up I thought I'd ask here.
Thanks!

Comment: have you reported a Qt bug for that? It would make sense to report it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently (http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/44612), you can't. You can just rename it by hand.
However, you can set the application name (not the .apk name) in the manifest file.